# Excel GoogleGeocode VB Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following function I have added reference to Microsoft XML 6.0 via Tools->References. I keep getting a "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined". Can any see the flaw? The debugger keeps highlighting "googleResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument" Thanks!

```
Function GoogleGeocode(address As String) As String
  Dim strAddress As String
  Dim strQuery As String
  Dim strLatitude As String
  Dim strLongitude As String

  strAddress = URLEncode(address)

  'Assemble the query string
  strQuery = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?"
  strQuery = strQuery & "address=" & strAddress
  strQuery = strQuery & "&sensor=false"

  'define XML and HTTP components
  Dim googleResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
  Dim oNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
  Dim oNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

  'create HTTP request to query URL - make sure to have
  'that last "False" there for synchronous operation

  googleService.Open "GET", strQuery, False
  googleService.send
  googleResult.LoadXML (googleService.responseText)

  Set oNodes = googleResult.getElementsByTagName("geometry")

  If oNodes.Length = 1 Then
    For Each oNode In oNodes
      strLatitude = oNode.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(0).Text
      strLongitude = oNode.ChildNodes(0).ChildNodes(1).Text
      GoogleGeocode = strLatitude & "," & strLongitude
    Next oNode
  Else
    GoogleGeocode = "Not Found (try again, you may have done too many too fast)"
  End If
End Function


Public Function URLEncode(StringVal As String, Optional SpaceAsPlus As Boolean = False) As String
  Dim StringLen As Long: StringLen = Len(StringVal)

  If StringLen > 0 Then
    ReDim result(StringLen) As String
    Dim i As Long, CharCode As Integer
    Dim Char As String, Space As String

    If SpaceAsPlus Then Space = "+" Else Space = "%20"

    For i = 1 To StringLen
      Char = Mid$(StringVal, i, 1)
      CharCode = Asc(Char)

      Select Case CharCode
      Case 97 To 122, 65 To 90, 48 To 57, 45, 46, 95, 126
        result(i) = Char
      Case 32
        result(i) = Space
      Case 0 To 15
        result(i) = "%0" & Hex(CharCode)
      Case Else
        result(i) = "%" & Hex(CharCode)
      End Select
    Next i
    URLEncode = Join(result, "")
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Have you added a reference to MSXML to your VBA project?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft XML 6.0 via Tools->References.

Comment: That works fine for me with that reference.  Check to see whether any other reference is tagged as "missing"

Comment: maybe the msxml dll is corrupted. I will check that out.

Comment: See if late binding works instead. Try `Dim googleResult As Object` followed by `Set googleResult = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")`

Comment: awesome! late binding works! thanks barrowc!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late binding solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same original problem and solved it by appending 60 to these two DIM statements:

```
Dim googleResult As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim googleService As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
```

That termination was suggested by VBA if you start retyping the line as soon as you get to the "MSXML2." portion.  It works fine on my system now.